# Ruby - Understanding string vs array comparison

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, algorithm

I'm working on a practice problem in Ruby. I already have the answer (below) but I'm not sure I understand how exactly one part of the answer works, specifically, how does `new_word` evaluate to a string if `|word|` is in an array. I may just be overlooking something super basic here but would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Prompt:
Write a method `abbreviate_sentence` that takes in a sentence string and returns a new sentence where every word longer than 4 characters has all of its vowels removed.

Answer:

````
  words = sent.split(" ")
  new_words = []

  words.each do |word|
    if word.length > 4
      new_word = abbreviate_word(word)
      new_words << new_word
    else
      new_words << word
    end
  end

  return new_words.join(" ")
end

def abbreviate_word(word)
  vowels = "aeiou"
  new_word = ""

  word.each_char do |char|
    if !vowels.include?(char)
      new_word += char
    end
  end

  return new_word
end

puts abbreviate_sentence("follow the yellow brick road") # => "fllw the yllw brck road"
puts abbreviate_sentence("what a wonderful life")        # => "what a wndrfl life" ```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're iterating over an array of strings, so each `|word|` isn't an array, it's a string. This code could be `sent.split(" ").map {|e| e.size > 4 ? e.gsub(/[aeiou]/, "") : e}.join(" ")`

Comment: @ggorlen `e.gsub(/[aeiou]/, "")` == `e.delete("aeiou")`

Comment: @steenslag nice, thanks. I'm sure there are other ways to shorten/improve it.

Comment: If you plan to answer your own question, please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. This lets other SO users know the question has been answered, and helps anyone with a similar question find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of @ggorlen:

You're iterating over an array of strings, so each |word| isn't an array, it's a string. This code could be sent.split(" ").map {|e| e.size > 4 ? e.gsub(/[aeiou]/, "") : e}.join(" ")